# JavaFX background visible between nodes when parent is scaled

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Pane with a grid of canvases in it. When these canvases are colored and I change the scale of the pane white lines appear between the canvases.

**Image before scaling**
[image]

**Scaled Image**
[image]

The code currently has a scene with a pane in it. When the mouse is dragged it finds a canvas at that location using a HashMap that stores all the canvases by their x and y indexes, the found canvas is colored black. When the mouse is scrolled the scale of the pane is changed by 0.1.

Code:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static final double SIZE = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        pane.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {
            int x = (int) (mouseEvent.getX() / SIZE);
            int y = (int) (mouseEvent.getY() / SIZE);

            Plot plot = new Plot(x, y);
            Canvas canvas = canvases.computeIfAbsent(plot, plot1 -> {
                Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas(SIZE, SIZE);
                pane.getChildren().add(newCanvas);
                newCanvas.setLayoutX(x * SIZE);
                newCanvas.setLayoutY(y * SIZE);
                return newCanvas;
            });

            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
        });

        scene.setOnScroll(scrollEvent -> {
            double scale = pane.getScaleX() + (scrollEvent.getDeltaY() > 0 ? 0.01 : -0.01);

            pane.setScaleX(scale);
            pane.setScaleY(scale);
        });

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private static class Plot {
        private final int x;
        private final int y;

        private Plot(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Plot plot = (Plot) o;
            return x == plot.x &&
                    y == plot.y;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(x, y);
        }
    }

    private final Map<Plot, Canvas> canvases = new HashMap<>();



}
```

Comment: I think this is due to int sizing but floating scaling being mapped to a distinct pixel grid.  Let’s say you have pos 1,1 and 2,2 this will be right on screen pixels, now scale by 1.25 and you have 1.25,1.25 and 2.5, 2.5. Now apply default [snapToPixel](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html?is-external=true#snapToPixelProperty) for the pane, and you get 1,1 and 3,3, leaving a gap between the scaled items, because a 1x1 pixel scaled by 1.25 will still be 1x1 with snap rendering.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense but I'm not sure it's the case. I tried changing snapToPixel to false for the pane and found no difference. I also tried setting a global css rule setting snapToPixel to false for everything and the issue still persisted.

Comment: Could be to do with canvas specifically and how it is internally implemented, I haven’t tried it with plain rectangles in a scene graph, but I guess that using that would not experience this issue.

Answer (score 2):

My initial guess was it might be because of using Canvas node, that it has something related to border aliasing issue. So I tried replacing all the Canvas nodes to Rectangles. But still the problem exists. I believe there should be something happening related to layouting using x and y.

While I cannot tell you the exact reason for this issue, I can suggest an alternate approach. Please note that I dont know the end usage of this implemenation or why you keep the Canvases in map. So the below approach is to let you know or give you the direction about how you can fix it.

**Alternate Approach #1:**

Instead of using many canvas nodes, try defining only one Canvas node that fit in the pane and paint the canvas as you draw. On checking for the zooming, it does not have any issue in spacing (as it is only one node).

Please check the below demo:

[image]

**[UPDATE]**

**Alternate Approach #2:**

The other approach is to use Path node. This approach also uses only one node for the entire drawing. The other advantage of using this is you can create as many paths as you want if you want to pick different brush colors. The other advantage is you can draw in the negative coords just as you did in your initial implemenation.

The idea is pretty much same as in canvas approach. As you drag, you draw a Path of the box using the mouse cooridinate. I updated the code in the below demo.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class CanvasDrawing extends Application {

    private static final double SIZE = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white;");

        // approachUsingCanvas(pane);
        approachUsingPath(pane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane,Color.RED);
        scene.setOnScroll(scrollEvent -> {
            double scale = pane.getScaleX() + (scrollEvent.getDeltaY() > 0 ? 0.01 : -0.01);
            pane.setScaleX(scale);
            pane.setScaleY(scale);
        });
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Canvas Drawing");
        stage.show();
    }

    private void approachUsingPath(Pane pane) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.setStrokeWidth(1);
        path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        path.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        pane.getChildren().add(path);
        pane.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {
            int x = (int) (mouseEvent.getX() / SIZE);
            int y = (int) (mouseEvent.getY() / SIZE);
            Plot plot = new Plot(x, y);
            if(!plots.contains(plot)){
                plots.add(plot);
                double sx = x * SIZE;
                double sy = y * SIZE;
                // Draw the box using Path
                path.getElements().addAll(new MoveTo(sx,sy),
                        new LineTo(sx+SIZE,sy),
                        new LineTo(sx+SIZE,sy+SIZE),
                        new LineTo(sx,sy+SIZE),
                        new LineTo(sx,sy));
            }
        });
    }

    private void approachUsingCanvas(Pane pane){
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.widthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());
        canvas.heightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());
        canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(Color.BLACK);
        pane.getChildren().add(canvas);

        pane.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {
            int x = (int) (mouseEvent.getX() / SIZE);
            int y = (int) (mouseEvent.getY() / SIZE);
            Plot plot = new Plot(x, y);
            if(!plots.contains(plot)){
                plots.add(plot);
                double sx = x * SIZE;
                double sy = y * SIZE;
                canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillRect(sx, sy, SIZE, SIZE);
            }
        });
    }

    private static class Plot {
        private final int x;
        private final int y;

        private Plot(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Plot plot = (Plot) o;
            return x == plot.x &&
                    y == plot.y;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(x, y);
        }
    }

    private final List<Plot> plots = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason I was using so many canvases was to allow for a drawing app in which there was no limit to the size of the canvas. Extending the canvas only works so long as you never want to draw in the negative x and negative y quadrants. I agree that the layout properties of the canvases are probably related to the issue, I'm just not sure how it can be fixed without sacrificing on essential functionality.

Comment: Ok I understand the need. Due you think the requirement of drawing in negative X/Y coordinate is possible with the above approach? I know that this is not related to actual issue mentioned in the question. But trying to understand the context.

Comment: I don't see a way to get all the functionality I need while only using a single canvas. It might be possible to achieve something similar to what I want by making each stroke its own node, but I worry that would be terrible for performance when there are 1000s of strokes on the screen.

Comment: I agree with that. There will be definitely some peformance issues when you have too many nodes in scene graph. Alternately you may consider using "Path" node as you draw. I updated the answer using the approach.

Comment: “a drawing app in which there was no limit to the size of the canvas” -> maybe [tile map technology](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/writing-a-tile-engine-in-javafx.html) might be useful for you.

Comment: I like the idea of using paths, I'm just not sure it would work past the simple example I gave in my original post. [Here's an example of my current application working](https://streamable.com/bj51yr) and here's its [github link](https://github.com/Zev-G/InfiniDrawTest). In my current project I'm solving the grid line issue by making the canvases 1 larger than they have to be so that they overlap, this really isn't an ideal solution and introduces problems in my undo and redoing.